# Anyone used Boost SERIALIZATION with Codegear Builder 2009 Successfully

Tags: c++builder, boost-serialization

If you have been successful in persisting your data, which type of stream did you get to work

```
Text or Binary
ANSI or UNICODE
```

Did you have to use any BOOST_ASSERTS or some extra MACRO or dance around the fairy ring at 4:00 am wearing your Moose sweater backwards.

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a posting for C++Builder 2010 (unfortunately I do not know of one for 2009), that shows the portions of the [Boost (1.39) that are included in the shipping product](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ddean/2009/09/23/34847).  The serialization library is listed as *not supported*.  Note the posting also includes a link to the source code they used in case someone wants to experiment with the unsupported libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. Wish all C++ compilers conformed to the same name mangeling standard. Then I could compile Boost using Mingw or DM and link the obj code into my Borland generated exe.

The good thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from. -- Andrew S. Tanenbaum

Comment: FTR, we just updated boost for C++Builder 2010 and that includes boost fixes which enable serialization to be used again.

Comment: Excellent. I shall endevour to get it working as it works well when it works <:->

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried, so I can't directly answer.  However, here are the boost 1.37.0 [test results for C++Builder 2009](http://bcbboost.sourceforge.net/test/1_37_0/cs-win32.html) (the column on the right, "borland-6.1.0").

You can see most things in 'serialization' pass the tests.  Some don't, so if you compare what you're trying to do to those it should help you to know what to avoid.  The test suites may also useful to you, because they can be used as code examples for using the features they test.

You may find other resources on the [C++ Builder Boost page](http://bcbboost.sourceforge.net/) to be useful too.

Comment: I do have a copy of this and have looked at it and what I am trying to do does seem possible. After 5 or 6 six days of chasing ones posterior I had hoped that someone else in the wide, wide world had already seen this problem and knew the 'Magic sequence of symbols and glyphs to gesture on the glowing enchanted glass'. Back to the Well of Souls for a midnight session.